# AWS CLI create encrypted key using sms not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-protect-data-at-rest-with-amazon-ec2-instance-store-encryption/ to generate a key to encrypt my EC2 instance. However, I'm totally stuck on this line:

```
aws --region us-east-one kms encrypt --key-id 'alias/EncFSForEC2InternalStorageKey' --plaintext "ThisIs-a-SecretPassword" --query CiphertextBlob --output text | base64 --decode > LuksInternalStorageKey
```

I'm getting the error:

```
An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the Encrypt
operation: Alias
arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:784754406091:alias/EncFSForEC2InternalStorageKey
is not found.
```

but my understand of the above command is that it would create the alias if it didn't already exist?

Comment: As StackOverflow is for questions related to development only, could you indicate how this *directly* influences your development experience?

Comment: Do you have a KMS key defined with that alias name? Also, the region name should be `us-east-1`, not `us-east-one`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I need to encrypt a production server that will hold confidential data

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I hadn't but I created one and it worked, thanks!